# Add FF App Menu Item (Restartless)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to create a Firefox add-on that is restartless and has a menu entry in the Firefox App Menu (preferably in the Options sub-menu). I cannot find anything anywhere on how to add an entry to the app menu while being restartless! I am building it with the Mozilla Addon Builder. Any and all help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there isn't really a way to do this. A "normal" restartless add-on has to [enumerate all open browser windows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/working_with_windows_in_chrome_code#Finding_already_opened_windows) and add a menu entry "manually" to the element with `id="appmenu-popup"`. It will also have to [watch for new windows being opened](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWindowWatcher#registerNotification%28%29) to make the same change there as well. While this is already complicated enough ([bug 675387](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=675387) is about making this simpler by allowing using overlays like in non-restartless add-ons) I strongly suspect that the Add-on SDK (that the Add-on Builder is based on) doesn't provide any way to do this at all. After all, it is only meant for add-ons that can live with a limited set of features.

Comment: ok, I talked to someone who said that he will work on adding a module for an app menu button to the Add-on SDK and eventually release it.